# Crystal Reports display records in column wise keep a heading to the starting of the row

Tags: crystal-reports, crystal-reports-2008

I want to change the format of the  data from:

```
1 xxxx
2 yyyy
3 zzzz
```

to:

```
ID       1    2    3
EmpName xxxx yyyy zzzz
```

Basically I want to add a heading to each row.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try using a subreport and try placing the fields that you want in the same order. Place the subreport in the GroupHeader on ID in the main report.

---

Though your question is not to the point and doesnt give any details, I assume you might want to drop a textfield on the report and Rename it to ID  and EmpName. -- However the order will be vertical and not horizontal.

Comment: Exactly,But I always want my data to be displayed in Horizontally.

Comment: @Srikanth This answer doesn't seem to address your question of displaying your records horizontally. Should it be accepted? Did you figure your problem out?

Comment: @Ryan Not yet ,I accept the understanding of "amazing".Let me know if u have a solution

Comment: @Srikanth You may want to un-accept the answer as most people will assume your problem is solved.

Comment: @Ryan do u have any solution for the above question

Comment: @Srikanth Not without a little more information about your data model and what you're trying to display. If it's just record IDs and record names you're trying to display horizontally, try using a crosstab.